# How to read and save an html text using Selenium RC?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

In the website I'm testing, I create a new customer. Once this customer is created a new id is assigned for that customer, which is not stored as a form field in the customer webpage but rather on the top page as pure text like (Customer 601619 - name1)

I have this html tag

```
<h1> Customer 601619 - name1 </h1>
```

My question is how to retrieve this customer id using Java selenium RC

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a side note, please note that Selenium RC is officially deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
String str = seleniumobj.getText("//h1");
System.out.println(str);
```

The above code prints  `Customer 601619 - name1` in console